# How to translate breadcrumbs

Tags: php, breadcrumb

Tell me how to translate breadcrumbs.
I'm using WP globus for translations, and breadcrumbs from the plugin Breadcrumb NavXT.

Comment: Please update your question in english, this is an english speaking stack. Once it's in english we can reopen the question

Comment: Breadcrumb plugins typically just use the post/page titles, so if they are translated then the breadcrumbs should be as well. If there's other text in the plugin then it should be translatable the same as any other plugin's text. You'd need to ask the developers of WP Globus how to use their plugin.